# HTML5 Video - are plugins required?

Tags: html, video, plugins

I really have researched this but I am still confused. In all of the HTML5 compatible browsers (although in this case I'm talking about Chrome 20 and Safari for Windows 5.1.7), if I specify some video using  tags, is the idea that this should play without the user having to install plug-ins? Or will the user have to install a plugin such as WMP / Quicktime? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

They will play without plugins. One of the key purposes of HTML5 is that you dont need anything but the browser to display content...and it works on all kinds of devices.

Answer (score 0):

No, no plugins are required. The code required to play the video comes as part of the browser.

The problem with entrusting this to the browser, though, is there is a current inconsistency in which video/audio formats each browser supports.

For example, Chrome and IE9 will play MP3 audio, but Firefox and Opera play a different format.